# Remove new lines after echoing HTML from PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, replace, newline

I have a Wordpress function that checks if a user has filled in some fields on his or her profile. If it is filled in, echo its contents, if not: don't. Here is a stripped down version of the fun

```
<ul>
    <?php if (get_the_author_meta('url',$theID)) : ?>
        <li class="url">
            <a href="<?php the_author_meta('url',$theID); ?>" title="">Website</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; // End check for url ?>
    <?php if ( get_the_author_meta('twitter',$theID)) : ?>
        <li class="twitter">
            <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta('twitter',$theID); ?>" title="">Twitter</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; // End check for twitter ?>
    <?php if ( get_the_author_meta('instagram',$theID)) : ?>
        <li class="instagram">
            <a href="http://instagram.com/<?php the_author_meta('instagram',$theID); ?>" title="">Instagram</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; // End check for instagram ?>
    <?php if ( get_the_author_meta('linkedin',$theID)) : ?>
        <li class="linkedin">
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/<?php the_author_meta('linkedin',$theID); ?>" title="">LinkedIn</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; // End check for linkedin ?>
</ul>
```

This works well. However, for layout purposes I am using `inline` on these elements and I can't use floats. As you may know, this causes "gaps" in between the elements because they are all echoed on new lines.

[image: gaps]

I don't want these gaps. I know I can solve it by an arbitrary negative margin, but I don't want to use it because I am using a responsive, percentage based layout. The solution would be to "fill the gaps" in HTML by glueing all HTML together without new lines. As an example:

Will create gaps when displayed inline:

```
<ul>
  <li>Twitter</li>
  <li>Instagram</li>
  <li>LinkedIn</li>
</ul>
```

Won't have gaps:

```
<ul>
  <li>Twitter</li><li>Instagram</li><li>LinkedIn</li>
</ul>
```

I am looking for a PHP solution (no CSS) that can get rid of all the new lines inside the `ul`, but I don't know where to start. Or, more precisely, I don't know where to put the function that removes the new lines. How can I wrap all that HTML, and then replace the new lines by ... *nothing*?

Comment: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Have you tried removing the space between the HTML and PHP in your source?

Comment: Well, instead of having HTML and PHP parts mixed together, you could gather the HTML code to output in a string – so that no whitespace occurs in the first place; but that would rather make templating messy. A second option would be to use an output buffer, and then replace the whitespace in that before outputting the buffer contents.

Comment: I personally in this case would prefer the comment method mentioned in the link already posted by APAD1 – that keeps the advantages of using PHP as a template language, does away with the unwanted effect, and with maybe an additional PHP comment above you won’t forget about it when modifying this template either.

Comment: @CBroe See my own answer. Thanks. Thanks APAD1 I only knew about the negative margin hack, not about the comment hack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="author-meta">
    <?php
        if (get_the_author_meta('url', $theID)) {
            $output = '<li class="url"><a href="' . get_the_author_meta('url', $theID) . '" title="">Website</a></li>';
        }
        if ( get_the_author_meta('twitter', $theID)) {
            $output .= '<li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/' . get_the_author_meta('twitter', $theID) . '" title="">Twitter</a></li>';
        }
        if ( get_the_author_meta('instagram', $theID)) {
            $output .= '<li class="instagram"><a href="http://instagram.com/' . get_the_author_meta('instagram', $theID) . '" title="">Instagram</a></li>';
        }
        if ( get_the_author_meta('linkedin', $theID)) {
            $output .= '<li class="linkedin"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/' . get_the_author_meta('linkedin', $theID) . '" title="">LinkedIn</a></li>';
        }
        echo $output;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Edit by Bram Vanroy: make sure to use `get_the_author_meta` instead of `the_author_meta` when using the function in PHP.

Comment: Why don't you just [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28464837/edit) your post?

Comment: I hate not being PSR-2 compliant.. Every comma needs 1 white space after :-) see http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/ it REALLY helps following this coding style..

Comment: No, what I meant was: why did you make a new answer and not edit the previous one?

Comment: Ah.. 'cause I'm a bit new here as logged in user. I've used Stackoverflow for years looking for answers and only recently felt the need to do something back and help others.. Just wanted to provide one copy/paste answer also for future users who have the same issue - didn't think of editing the other one. Good suggestion, I'll do that next time :-)

Comment: Glad to be of help, mate! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
$string = str_replace("\n", "", $string);
```

or:

```
$string = str_replace("\n\r", "", $string);
```

(where $string is the html you want to get on one line)

Comment: That's my problem, not all HTML is always outputed so I don't know how to get the string.

Comment: In that case: can't you start with an empty variable - like `$output=''`. Then in all the conditional statements just do (e.g.) `$output .= '<li class="url"><a href="' . the_author_meta('url',$theID) . '" title="">Website</a></li>'` (witout any line breaks) and in the end `echo $output;` ?

Comment: That's another option indeed.

Comment: It would be the option that uses the least resources.. if you can avoid preg_replace() you should..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
ob_start();
//echo whatever stuff you need
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, NULL, ob_get_clean());
```

Using `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n` or `\r\n` will catch line breaks regardless of platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use buffer for that :

```
<?php 
function remove_white_spaces($buffer){
    return trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $buffer));
}
ob_start('remove_white_spaces'); 
?>
<ul>
    <?php if (get_the_author_meta('url',$theID)) : ?>
        <li class="url">
            <a href="<?php the_author_meta('url',$theID); ?>" title="">Website</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; // End check for url ?>
    <?php if ( get_the_author_meta('twitter',$theID)) : ?>
        <li class="twitter">
            <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta('twitter',$theID); ?>" title="">Twitter</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; // End check for twitter ?>
    <?php if ( get_the_author_meta('instagram',$theID)) : ?>
        <li class="instagram">
            <a href="http://instagram.com/<?php the_author_meta('instagram',$theID); ?>" title="">Instagram</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; // End check for instagram ?>
    <?php if ( get_the_author_meta('linkedin',$theID)) : ?>
        <li class="linkedin">
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/<?php the_author_meta('linkedin',$theID); ?>" title="">LinkedIn</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; // End check for linkedin ?>
</ul>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Catch all the output on a buffer, run a function to replace new lines with blanks, and release the buffer.

Comment: _“run a function to replace new lines with blanks”_ – a single blank between the element tags would still cause the effect; _all_ white space between them has to be removed. This however gets problematic, because you can not remove whitespace in the tags themselves (between `li` and `class`, `a` and `href`, `title`) or in the link text as well. So you would have to use a rather ugly regular-expression-to-modify-HTML-solution here … that’s why I really would prefer the comments method, as said in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your ul font-size to 0 and apply the size to your li

```
font-size: 15px; display: inline-block;
```

Comment: I specifically asked for a PHP solution and not a CSS one.

Comment: This is not a solution. This is *the* problem.

Comment: What kind of reply is that. If you can kill the problem at the root, i.e. Before outputting the hotel,  then that's  better  than any case solution.

Comment: Yes. The problem is not PHP. The problem is HTML/CSS related. What you want is that the spaces between `li` should not be considered as whitespaces. There is a lot to read about that, and no solution come to PHP http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: That's exactly the point. With a PHP solution, you can change the output HTML to get rid of the problem. Which is perfectly possible without CSS.

Comment: Avoiding a problem does not mean that you solved it. I answered to this question after many PHP answers were given. I wouldn't have answered to give a nth PHP code for gluing li tags together. Oh wait, if you really want to...

Comment: Avoiding a problem means that you don't have to solve it.  And I'll keep it at that.

Comment: But you also have to consider that many users could read the differents answers to your question to find the solution which fits their needs. And your question is very good, although i don't have the same sensibility on the answer to give.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment by @APAD1 and feedback by @CBRoe, I decided to go with the comment method. It works flawlessly, though the HTML output isn't pretty (empty comments, byebye semantics).

```
<ul class="author-meta">
    <?php if (get_the_author_meta('url',$theID)) : ?><li class="url">
            <a href="<?php the_author_meta('url',$theID); ?>" title="">Website</a>
        </li><?php endif; // End check for url ?><!--
    --><?php if ( get_the_author_meta('twitter',$theID)) : ?><li class="twitter">
            <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta('twitter',$theID); ?>" title="">Twitter</a>
        </li><?php endif; // End check for twitter ?><!--
    --><?php if ( get_the_author_meta('instagram',$theID)) : ?><li class="instagram">
            <a href="http://instagram.com/<?php the_author_meta('instagram',$theID); ?>" title="">Instagram</a>
        </li><?php endif; // End check for instagram ?><!--
    --><?php if ( get_the_author_meta('linkedin',$theID)) : ?><li class="linkedin">
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/<?php the_author_meta('linkedin',$theID); ?>" title="">LinkedIn</a>
        </li><?php endif; // End check for linkedin ?>
</ul>
```

Note that the comments should be *outside* the `if` clauses, because if they are inside they might not be echoed corretly, e.g. missing a opening or closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<ul><?php 
$output = '';
if (get_the_author_meta('url', $theID)) {
    $output .= '<li class="url"><a href="' . the_author_meta('url',$theID) . '" title="">Website</a></li>';
} elseif (get_the_author_meta('twitter', $theID)) {
    $output .= '<li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/' . the_author_meta('twitter', $theID) . '" title="">Twitter</a></li>';
} elseif (get_the_author_meta('instagram', $theID)) {
    $output .= '<li class="instagram"><a href="http://instagram.com/' .  the_author_meta('instagram', $theID) . '" title="">Instagram</a></li>';
} elseif (get_the_author_meta('linkedin',$theID)) {
    $output .= '<li class="linkedin"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/' . the_author_meta('linkedin', $theID) . '" title="">LinkedIn</a></li>';
}
echo $output;
?></ul>
```

Comment: The elseifs should all be individual if's. But the rest is looking good!

Comment: Well, then you can make my day and accept my answer :-)

Comment: Please first change the elseifs to ifs.

Answer (score 0):

To make an easy to use version, you can store all your websites data in an array:

```
$site=Array(
   "url"=>"Website",
   "twitter"=> "Twitter",
   "instagram"=> "Instagram",
   "linkedin"=>"LinkedIn"
);
```

And then generating the whole list. I used a simple sample case where all domains are .com. You will have to improve the array format if you want more information to be stored.

```
<ul><?php
foreach($site as $k=>$v)
if (get_the_author_meta($k,$theID))
   echo '<li class="'.$k.'"><a href="'
      .(($k=="url")?"":"http://$k.com/")
      .the_author_meta($k,$theID).'">'.$v.'</a></li>';
?></ul>
```

Don't forget to remove your empty title attribute in your `a` tags.

*Note that there are others CSS alternatives: using `display:table` on your `ul` and `display:table-cell` on your `li`, or using `display: flex` and so on.*